# Completeness of a certain Lipschitz function space (w/o measure theory)

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, measure-theory, metric-spaces

I found this problem in an old analysis 2 (**before** I learned about anything measure theory related) exam of mine. We had to prove that
$$
X := \left \lbrace f: [0, 1]^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}: \lvert f(x) - f(y) \rvert \leq \lVert x - y \rVert_2, ~\forall x, y \in [0, 1]^2 \right \rbrace
$$
is complete with respect to the metric $d: X \times X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is given by
$$
d(f, g) := \int_{[0, 1]^2} \lvert f(x) - g(x) \rvert \lVert x \rVert_2^2~\mathrm{d}x.
$$

I really have trouble tackling this without any measure theorey results. Even with measure theory it seems rather hard. I would start by choosing a $d$-Cauchy-sequence $(f_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq X$   and trying to prove that a subsequence $(f_{k_m})_{m \in \mathbb{N}}$ with $d(f_{k_m}, f_{k_\ell})$ very, very small  converges. I would love argue with converging sums of $\lvert f_{k_m}(x) - f_{k_\ell}(x) \rvert$ like one does in measure theory...

(I would prefer not using Fatou's Lemma, the fact that $L^p$ convergent series converge pointwise a.e. in a subsequence etc...)

Comment: I believe that any Cauchy sequence will be equicontinuous. The Arzela Ascoli theorem shows that there is a uniformly convergent subsequence. The limit $\bar{f}$ of the unifomly convergent subsequence will be in $X$ since $$\lvert \bar{f}(x) - \bar{f}(y) \rvert =\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\lvert {f}_{n_k}(x) - {f}_{n_k}(y) \rvert\leq \lVert x - y \rVert_2.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sequences in $X$ are equi-continuous. It is sufficient to show that a Cauchy sequence in $X$ is bounded in the $\max$-norm.

Let $x_0\in(0,1)^2$. Then
$$
|f(x_0)-g(x_0)| \le |f(x)-g(x)| + 2 \|x-x_0\|_2 \le \frac12 |f(x)-g(x)|^2 + 2\sqrt2+\frac12
$$
for all $x$ (using $2|a| \le a^2+1$). Now we can integrate with respect to $x$, but only on a subset, where $\|x\|_2$ is bounded away from zero. Then
$$
|f(x_0)-g(x_0)| \le \frac12 \int_{x\in (1/2,1)} |f(x)-g(x)|^2 dx + C
\le \int_{x\in (1/2,1)} |f(x)-g(x)|^2\cdot \|x\|_2^2 dx + C\le d(f,g)+C
$$
with some constant independent of $x_0$.
The right-hand side is independent of $x_0$, so we can take the maximum over $x_0$. This proves that bounded sequences in $X$ are bounded with respect to the $\max$-norm. Arzela-Ascoli theorem gives convergence, passing to the pointwise limit in the inequality defining $X$ shows that the limit is in $X$.  In, addition convergence in the metric $d$ can be proven.

Comment: Thank you, I think I see where this is going. But there is no square in the metric, I think you only misread that but that does not change anything.